# Where did a log message come from

Tags: java, logging, netbeans, reverse-engineering, netbeans-6.9

what is the easiest way to find out where a log message came from? My log file contains a warning, and I would like to have a look at the code that wrote it. However, NetBeans 6.9 does not make it easy for me to do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A practical approach would be to copy the log message or a part of it, then right-click on your project node and then in the context menu click "Search". Paste your copied text in the search field and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You could grep within your code for the string in the log file. If you can't find it then search for a substring from within it as it may be build up from many concatenated parts.

Comment: I could, but that is not exactly easy. Can grep give me the line number of the matches?

Comment: Yes, [`-n, --line-number`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/grep/); NetBeans also accpets regex in the `Find in Projects…` doalog.